# How to execute a query in VS Code for Cosmos DB?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-cosmosdb

I have installed an extension for having access to a Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB in VS Code, and I'm able to see the documents inside as expected.

[image]

However, I wasn't able to figure out how to run a query that allow me to filter results based on different conditions e.g: `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.DocumentId = 123`

Is there a way to run SQL queries in VS Code on a Cosmos DB? I couldn't find any helpful tutorial and by installing "mssql" extension seems that is mainly focused on ADO.NET connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the statements in the cosmos db extension:

> Browse and query your MongoDB databases both locally and in the cloud
>   using scrapbooks with rich Intellisense then connect to Azure to
>   manage your Cosmos DB databases with support for MongoDB, Graph
>   (Gremlin), and SQL (previously known as DocumentDB).

You could follow below official example of Scrapbooks to query your sql api db with mongo shell syntax.

[image]

E.G.

```
db.coll.find({"DocumentId" :123})
```

---

Update:

Sorry for the late updates. I got 2 tools for you:

1.**CosmosDbExplorer** :https://www.bruttin.com/CosmosDbExplorer/

2.**Azure Storage Explorer**: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Jay! It worked! However, this will only help to do it with the Mongo DB syntax right? The fact is that I would need to do it with SQL syntax because of the nature of the project. Do you know any other tool for that purpose?

Comment: @MauroBilotti As i know, there is only the data explorer in the azure portal which supports sql syntax to access your cosmos db sql api:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/14917053-azure-documentdb-explorer-standalone-desktop-app-f

Comment: Yes, is the one that I'm using. Sadly, I don't really like it, that's why I as searching for an alternative.

Comment: @MauroBilotti Cheers! I found a nice desktop tool for you which implements same function as data explorer on the portal,https://www.bruttin.com/CosmosDbExplorer/

Comment: @MauroBilotti If you satisfied with that, you could mark this answer for others' reference,thanks a lot.

Comment: @MauroBilotti I edited the workarounds in my answer.

Comment: With Azure Storage Explorer now deprecated, it's unbelievable to see even in 2021 that there is no good tool by Microsoft for querying Cosmos Db directly. They say, move to the web UI for it but it just doesn't make the cut for me.

Comment: Yeah, the web ui is not remotely close to an enterprise tool.  I'm shocked that that's their response.  Quite often, I will be in the middle of investigating an issue and have lots of query tabs up, then get called away to a meeting or some other task.  And when I return, my session is timed out and I've lost all of my queries if I haven't manually backed them up into a local text editor.  This is a terrible dev experience!

Answer (score 0):

This tool might help: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cosmosdb

The issue is that they do not explain how to use and manipulate SQL API. Please share if anyone has an idea for using SQL API like the Mango DB and this tool.